# Java: reading numeric value from a field as string is showing with decimals

Tags: java, formatting, apache-poi, xlsx

I have a field in the input xlsx file which can contain either email or mobile number. While reading it, I am having the following logic -

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("./TXN_Log_Mar_18_input.xlsx"));
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
while (rowIterator.hasNext() && cnt <maxRows) {
    System.out.println("\n\nNew row "+cnt+" ");
    Row row = rowIterator.next();
    if(row.getCell(11).toString() !="" || row.getCell(12).toString() !="")
    {

        String debitUser = row.getCell(11).toString();
        System.out.println("input mobile? "+debitUser);
        if(emailFormat(debitUser) || mobileFormat(debitUser))
        {
            response  = umCall(debitUser);
        }   

    }
}
```

With a proper 10 digit mobile number, following is the output -

```
input mobile? 7.358681129E9
```

Comment: Try using `DataFormatter` as shown in [Getting the cell contents](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents). `DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();` ... `String debitUser = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(11));`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Apache POI, so I recommend you to not use toString() method. Use getCellValue() methods instead.

If you know the type of the value contained by your cell, you can use specific method like getNumericCellValue() that returns a double. Then it is up to you to format data as you wish.

```
double cellValue = row.getCell(11).getNumericCellValue();
System.out.println("input mobile? " + (int) cellValue);
```

Something like that maybe.

See Cell documentation to find the best way to do.

https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html

Also I recommend you to check the type of your cell before dealing with data.

Comment: To test cell type, you can use getCellType() and compare to CellType.NUMERIC.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the type returned by getCell(), but I'm guessing it is a BigDecimal, or something very similar. BigDecimal has toPlainString(), which prevents formatting large numbers using exponential notation. Whatever the type returned, look at its methods for something similar.

Comment: Here the java doc for Row class: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getCell-int-